# How to scale an alphaMap of THREE.JS material?

Tags: three.js

I have applied a texture to material object, like so:

`material.alphaMap = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(o.texture);`

and I just want to scale it with a number (2, 3, 4, and so on..).

How can I do it?

I tried to edit properties of this object, used methods, searched on Google...but nothing works for now.

Comment: what do you mean scale? You can scale a texture with `texture.repeat.set(2,2)` for example. In your case `material.alphaMap.repeat.set(2,2)`

Comment: @gman unfortunately you can't apply this to a single texture. This repeat is global per material, but defined with some weird priority list. If there is another texture somewhere, with repeat set to say 4, that one could override the `alphaMap`. You could be calling `repeat.set()` here until the end of the world, it could have no effect. This design is really confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

material.alphaMap.repeat.set(2,2)
But their repeat is shared, which will affect your map and other textures.